# How to install cvblob on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, cmake

I am trying to do blob detection in `OpenCV` on `Ubuntu 12.04` system. I need to install `cvblob` library for this. So, i downloaded the zip file, extracted it and tried to run `cmake`. But everytime i run this

```
cmake . -DOpenCV_DIR=<directory path>
```

it shows the following error

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
```

and also the following error:

```
CMake Error: The source directory "/home/arvindnarayanan/Documents/cvblob" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
```

What do i do?

Comment: cvbloblibs is *very* old and using the outdated c-api. maybe you're better off not using it at all, and instead go with the c++ api and [findContours](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours)

Answer (score 0):

Both of your problems are essentially CMake issues, not cvblob issues.

Here is a full example how to compile cvblob on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. It assumes OpenCV has been installed into the system successfully.

```
dev@dev:~$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=precise
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS"
dev@dev:~$
```

First get cvblob sources from http://cvblob.googlecode.com/files/cvblob-0.10.4-src.tgz (the location of latest version at the moment of writing) and untar the package:

```
dev@dev:~$ tar xzvf cvblob-0.10.4-src.tgz 
cvblob/
cvblob/CMakeLists.txt
cvblob/CMakeScripts/
cvblob/CMakeScripts/Toolchain-mingw32.cmake
cvblob/COPYING
cvblob/COPYING.LESSER
cvblob/ChangeLog
cvblob/Doxyfile
cvblob/README
cvblob/contrib/
cvblob/contrib/cvBlobDLL/
cvblob/contrib/cvBlobDLL/README
cvblob/contrib/cvBlobDLL/TestDLL/
cvblob/contrib/cvBlobDLL/TestDLL/Debug/
cvblob/contrib/cvBlobDLL/TestDLL/ReadMe.txt
cvblob/contrib/cvBlobDLL/TestDLL/Release/
cvblob/contrib/cvBlobDLL/TestDLL/TestDLL.c
cvblob/contrib/cvBlobDLL/TestDLL/TestDLL.vcproj
cvblob/contrib/cvBlobDLL/TestDLL/imgout.png
cvblob/contrib/cvBlobDLL/TestDLL/stdafx.cpp
cvblob/contrib/cvBlobDLL/TestDLL/stdafx.h
cvblob/contrib/cvBlobDLL/TestDLL/targetver.h
cvblob/contrib/cvBlobDLL/TestDLL/test.png
cvblob/contrib/cvBlobDLL/cvblobDLL/
cvblob/contrib/cvBlobDLL/cvblobDLL/Debug/
cvblob/contrib/cvBlobDLL/cvblobDLL/Release/
cvblob/contrib/cvBlobDLL/cvblobDLL/cvblobDLL.cpp
cvblob/contrib/cvBlobDLL/cvblobDLL/cvblobDLL.h
cvblob/contrib/cvBlobDLL/cvblobDLL/cvblobDLL.sln
cvblob/contrib/cvBlobDLL/cvblobDLL/cvblobDLL.suo
cvblob/contrib/cvBlobDLL/cvblobDLL/cvblobDLL.vcproj
cvblob/contrib/cvBlobDLL/cvblobDLL/dllmain.cpp
cvblob/contrib/cvBlobDLL/cvblobDLL/stdafx.cpp
cvblob/contrib/cvBlobDLL/cvblobDLL/stdafx.h
cvblob/contrib/cvBlobDLL/cvblobDLL/targetver.h
cvblob/cvBlob/
cvblob/cvBlob/CMakeLists.txt
cvblob/cvBlob/cvaux.cpp
cvblob/cvBlob/cvblob.cpp
cvblob/cvBlob/cvblob.h
cvblob/cvBlob/cvcolor.cpp
cvblob/cvBlob/cvcontour.cpp
cvblob/cvBlob/cvlabel.cpp
cvblob/cvBlob/cvtrack.cpp
cvblob/cvBlobConfig.cmake.in
cvblob/cvblob.pc.cmake.in
cvblob/doc/
cvblob/samples/
cvblob/samples/Makefile
cvblob/samples/red_object_tracking.cpp
cvblob/samples/red_object_tracking.txt
cvblob/test/
cvblob/test/CMakeLists.txt
cvblob/test/EnterExitCrossingPaths2front_blobs.mpeg
cvblob/test/EnterExitCrossingPaths2front_blobs.txt
cvblob/test/test.cpp
cvblob/test/test.png
cvblob/test/test_random.cpp
cvblob/test/test_tracking.cpp
dev@dev:~$
```

As you can see there is `cvblob/CMakeLists.txt` that is required by CMake. You get the second error because you're saying to CMake to look from wrong directory:

```
dev@dev:~$ cmake .
CMake Error: The source directory "/home/dev" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
dev@dev:~$
```

You get the first error because you didn't realize that `<directory path>` is a placeholder text you're supposed to replace with a real directory path:

```
dev@dev:~$ cmake . -DOpenCV_DIR=<directory path>
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
dev@dev:~$
```

Instead you should have written:

```
dev@dev:~$ cmake . -DOpenCV_DIR=/usr/local/
```

Where `/usr/local/` is a real and correct path in your system.

So how to build the library correctly ?

```
dev@dev:~$ cd cvblob/
dev@dev:~/cvblob$ mkdir build
dev@dev:~/cvblob$ cd build
dev@dev:~/cvblob/build$ cmake ..
-- The C compiler identification is GNU
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
running mkdir -p "/home/dev/cvblob/build/unix-install/"  2>&1
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/dev/cvblob/build
dev@dev:~/cvblob/build$ make
Scanning dependencies of target cvblob
[ 11%] Building CXX object lib/CMakeFiles/cvblob.dir/cvblob.o
[ 22%] Building CXX object lib/CMakeFiles/cvblob.dir/cvlabel.o
[ 33%] Building CXX object lib/CMakeFiles/cvblob.dir/cvaux.o
[ 44%] Building CXX object lib/CMakeFiles/cvblob.dir/cvcontour.o
[ 55%] Building CXX object lib/CMakeFiles/cvblob.dir/cvtrack.o
[ 66%] Building CXX object lib/CMakeFiles/cvblob.dir/cvcolor.o
Linking CXX shared library libcvblob.so
[ 66%] Built target cvblob
Scanning dependencies of target test
[ 77%] Building CXX object test/CMakeFiles/test.dir/test.o
Linking CXX executable ../bin/test
[ 77%] Built target test
Scanning dependencies of target test_random
[ 88%] Building CXX object test/CMakeFiles/test_random.dir/test_random.o
Linking CXX executable ../bin/test_random
[ 88%] Built target test_random
Scanning dependencies of target test_tracking
[100%] Building CXX object test/CMakeFiles/test_tracking.dir/test_tracking.o
Linking CXX executable ../bin/test_tracking
[100%] Built target test_tracking
dev@dev:~/cvblob/build$ sudo make install
[sudo] password for dev: 
[ 66%] Built target cvblob
[ 77%] Built target test
[ 88%] Built target test_random
[100%] Built target test_tracking
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: "Release"
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/cvblob/cvBlobConfig.cmake
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/cvblob.pc
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/cvblob.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/libcvblob.so
-- Removed runtime path from "/usr/local/lib/libcvblob.so"
dev@dev:~/cvblob/build$
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try this url to download source for installation of cvblob 
http://code.google.com/p/cvblob/downloads/detail?name=cvblob-0.10.4-src.tgz&can=2&q=

you required the support of cmake & make